# Errors compiling pin tool with python includes, getting error C2872: 'UINT32' : ambiguous symbol

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, intel-pin

I'm trying to compile pin tool with `Python.h` and am getting more then 100 errors about ambiguous symbols.

I tried to separate the `include` to different namespace but it generated many other errors.

Same happens when including `windows.h`.

All the errors looks like:

`D:\proj\Pin\source\include\pin\gen\types_core.TLH(67): error C2872: 'INT32' : ambiguous symbol could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\basetsd.h(72) : int INT32 or      D:\proj\pin\Pin\source\include\pin\gen\types_foundation.TLH(88) : LEVEL_BASE::INT32' D:\proj\pin\Pin\source\include\pin\gen\types_core.TLH(81) : 
see reference to class template instantiation 'LEVEL_CORE::INDEX<dummy>' being compiled`

Do you know about a quick fix for this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use the Windows.h header you must use it in its own namespace:

```
namespace WINDOWS
{
    #include <Windows.h>
}
```

And then use something from Windows.h by using its namespace:

```
WINDOWS::DWORD foo; // use WINDOWS namespace
```

If you don't use a namespace for the windows.h header you'll get tons of name collisions with various headers from PIN itself.

**edit**:

Just remembered that is was mentioned somewhere on the manual (see: "Conflicts between Pin and Windows"):

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/65163/Pin/html/index.html#RESTRICTIONS

Comment: It would be a hell redefining all the PIN or Python references to UINT32... There must be a better way to do it.

Comment: @user1618465 I think you misunderstood my answer or the PIN ducumentation: you don't have to redefine the types **inside** PIN, Windows or python headers (or whatever). Just use a namespace in **your** Pintool. That's completely  different...