# PIN with python includes tool. Ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, intel-pin

I'm having the same problem than [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024164/errors-compiling-pin-tool-with-python-includes-getting-error-c2872-uint32).

Basically I am trying to compile a PIN tool that uses `Python.h`.

There are some types that are called the same for `Windows.h` and `PIN.h` and either of them declared a namespace for them so I'm getting `error C2872: 'UINT32' : ambiguous symbol` 
The problem is that my PIN tool  imports `PIN.h` and `Python.h` (which imports at the same time `Windows.h`) and both of them have same name types so the compiler doesn't know what type is each one and i'm getting the ambiguous symbols error

I cant use the solution:

```
namespace WINDOWS
{
    #include <Windows.h>
}
```

or

```
namespace PIN
{
    #include <PIN.h>
}
```

Because there are too many reference to them that need to be renamed and that would be a mess (PIN and Windows.h libraries uses `UINT32` or `CONTEXT` a lot of times).

Is there any elegant way to fix this?

Comment: hi, how did you solve this problem?

Comment: I dindn't find away to fix it and since PIN is closed source... They should encapsulate the PIN include in a namespace but for big already existing projects its a mess dealing with it :/